# I got an error and my joystick it doesn't remain in the cameraView

Tags: unity-game-engine, joystick

When I play the game , my script got an error and my joystick just runs in the left corner and can be unreachable . I get this script from internet , if you know any other scripts that works properly , please help. I tried to make the player move left and right but it doesn't work with buttons . I only found scripts with Rigidbody2d and mine is 3d

```css
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player_Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public float speed = 5.0f;
    private bool touchStart = false;
    private Vector2 pointA;
    private Vector2 pointB;

    public Transform FixedJoystick;
   

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            pointA = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.transform.position.z));

           
           FixedJoystick.transform.position = pointA * -1;
            GetComponent<FixedJoystick>().enabled = true;

        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            touchStart = true;
            pointB = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
        }
        else
        {
            touchStart = false;
        }

    }
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (touchStart)
        {
            Vector2 offset = pointB - pointA;
            Vector2 direction = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(offset, 1.0f);
            moveCharacter(direction * -1);

           FixedJoystick.transform.position = new Vector2(pointA.x + direction.x, pointA.y + direction.y) * -1;
        }
        else
        {
            FixedJoystick.GetComponent<FixedJoystick>().enabled = false;

        }

    }
    void moveCharacter(Vector2 direction)
    {
        player.Translate(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

[Picture before starting the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIkBq.png)
[Picture after starting the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GKEN.png)

Comment: Well read what it does and apply it to 3d, tbh for the most part it is similar. Plus, there are plenty of controllers around, as well as if you add some debugging you can probably work out what is wrong

Comment: Recommend debug by printing the values of pointA and pointB.